# Why function aren't hoisted after return statement?

Tags: javascript

```
const func = () => {
  someFunction() // error here
  
  return function someFunction() {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}

func()
```

I've created closure and wanted to check hoisting inside of `func` function. Each time when you create function declaration it hoists your variable up to the top. Why is `someFunction` not hoisted?

Comment: See here: https://blog.logrocket.com/demystifying-function-and-variable-hoisting-in-javascript/

Answer (score 8):

When you put a function after `return` statement, it no longer is a function declaration, but rather a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). Unlike declarations, function expressions are not hoisted.

> Function expressions in JavaScript are not hoisted, unlike function
> declarations.
>
> - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Function_expression_hoisting)

Answer (score 6):

You have a (named) [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) in your [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). This function is not a [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) and because of this, it is not hoisted.

Another reason is, a function expression has no name. That means, you can not access it by the a name outside of the function. The name of a function expression is only available inside of the function with it name (for example for recursions).